# Set random Image

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently developing an android application under xamarin, I'll need a little help.

I would like to load images from a button (button image), randomly, but i tried, i can't do.

This is how it works:

```
BtnMonster.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.mst1);
```

now, I'm trying something like that:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Img = "mst" + rnd.Next(1, 20);
BtnMonster.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Img);
```

But it doesn't work, and I don't know how to do.

If anyone had any idea?

Comment: How about making an array of your Drawables, and use a random number as an index in the array?

Comment: use DataBinding! That when you have an Observable object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface, you can change the image in the BindingContext and have it updated in real time otherwise, the image source might have been updated but not replicated to the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood right, this is what you want

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var imageName = "mst" + rnd.Next(1, 20);
int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", PackageName);
BtnMonster.SetImageResource(resID);
```

here, `imageName` is your drawable image name.

Answer (score 0):

You've chosen to use `Resources` so it's a bit trickier to load anything from it. Even though you've specified names for your resources, they are accessible through properties which are generated by your IDE.

---

First thing you have to do is to create an array ( or other collection type ) that will contain every image you need :

```
Image[] images = new Image[20];
```

Then you need to fill this up with your resource images ( since you've put them into resources ).

```
images[0] = Resources.Drawable.mst1;
images[1] = Resources.Drawable.mst2;
// ...
images[19] = Resources.Drawable.mst20;
```

You can use reflection to minimize the code but the effect would be essentially the same.

After making this you can pick and set your randomized image by choosing random image index and put item from that index as a parameter to the `SetImageResource` button.

```
Random rand = new Random().Next(0, 19);
BtnMonster.SetImageResource(images[rand]);
```